# Error in cypress when trying to find an id that starts with a number

Tags: typescript, cypress, react-testing-library

I am trying to find an element by id with cypress but when I use cypress  selector playground it gives the below code

```
get("#\33 -2")
```

but when I run this in cypress I get an error

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # -2

I even try add the id manually like:

```
get("#33-2")
```

still doesn't work. With classes everything work find! but not id.
Here is an example of the element I am trying to target

```
<div id="1-20">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cy.get("#1-20").should('exist')
```

Cypress actually returned a strange string, which itself gave an error, but writing the ID manually the code worked.

https://prnt.sc/1gqnbul

Answer (score 1):

I tried it locally and `#1-20` worked fine.

```
cy.get("#1-20").should('have.text', 'Hello world')
```

[image: test runner]

Comment: so I have a grid of row and columns and   the reason why get("#\33 -2")  wasn't working is because cypress was check all item in the grid from 0 , 1, 2, 3 etc. I don't have an item in the grid that's 33-2. but I tried a smaller number 10-20 and it work. thank you

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :)